# Setting specific parameters to Scanner input (Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm coming at this very early in my programming journey so apologies if the answer is obvious.

Is it possible to set specific parameters, or conditions, to the keyboard input when using Scanner? In my particular situation im looking to force a limit of 3 characters only, after that no further characters will be registered when typing.

Obvious follow on from this could be other conditions like forced upper or lower case input etc.

Many thanks

Comment: If you want to force the user input to be 3 then you will either have to read your characters one at a time and appending them to a `String` from there, it should be easy to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force the keyboard to stop accepting input, or force input to be uppercase or lowercase. 
What you can do is use java.util.Scanner to only record/grab 3 characters of user input (keyboard) and then take that input and change it to be uppercase or lowercase.

For Example:
  `Scanner.next().toUpperCase();`

Here are the docs for java.util.Scanner [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)